# clear() does not clear the textbox with selenium and python and firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

`clear()` does not work in this case. I am getting append after append.
`searchForMovie.clear()` is not working... I have also tried to send
 `CTRL + 'a'`, and then the `DELETE`. Again all I got are just appends...

```
 for movie in allMissing:

            time.sleep (10)

            searchForMovie = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until \
                (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-text")))  

            searchForMovie.send_keys (movie)

            # click
            enter = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until \
                (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-submit")))  

            driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click()", enter)


            # clear the search text box
            searchForMovie = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until \
                (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-text")))

            searchForMovie.clear()
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691625/363573

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear the textbox you need to induce *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` set to `element_to_be_clickable`, next invoke `click()` on the *WebElement* and  then invoke `clear()` as follows :

```
# clear the search text box
searchForMovie = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-text")))
searchForMovie.click()
searchForMovie.clear()
```

Comment: I got this error message, after trying your solution.  The element reference of <input id="search-text" name="nm" type="text"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: Once you `searchForMovie.send_keys(movie)` and subsequently `driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click()", enter)` the _HTML DOM_ is bound to change. So you need to come back to the same url where you started looking out for `searchForMovie = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until \
                (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-text")))`

Comment: This is not working, i tried it on Instagram login.

Comment: So in what context does that clear() API entry point function by design? It's clearly some kind of special-casing, but not documented accessibly to us.

Answer (score 4):

In case `.clear()` does not work you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#...your code (I was using python 3)

driver.find_element_by_id('foo').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
driver.find_element_by_id('foo').send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Comment: not working pls stop giving wrong answer

Comment: Actually, oddly, this was the only answer variant  that worked for me - I was having trouble clearing a password field, and all the variants of using clear() didn't work, despite the field being clickable and displayed.

Comment: This is a valid solution but on Mac OS it should be `Keys.COMMAND`

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be as easy as:

```
driver.execute_script("$('#search-text').val('');")
```

If you want to do it without jQuery, you could use plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('search-text').value = '';
```

Comment: This solution does not appear to trigger a 'change' event.

Comment: Also, the change happens asynchronistically with subsequent python code.