# InvalidElementStateException when attempting to clear text through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

The web application I am testing requires confirmation when deleting a record.

I have created a test to enter in a valid reason for deleting this record.

The code to do this is as follows:

```
DeleteFieldButton.
            Click();
        WaitMethods.WaitForElementToBeDisplayed(RemovalReason, 20);
        RemovalReason
            .Click();
        RemovalReason
            .Clear();
        RemovalReason
            .SendKeys("Automated Test - Delete Field");
```

The XPath to the text box is as follows:

```
private Label RemovalReason = new Label(By.XPath("//*[@placeholder = 'Removal reason']"));
```

Whenever the test is run the following exception is returned.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Cannot clear By.XPath: //*[@placeholder = 'Removal reason'] as it is 
not declared as a writable text element
Source=web
StackTrace:
at web.Elements.Common.Element.Clear()
at Daera.Efs.Test.E2e.PageObjects.ApplicationSummary.DeleteField(String 
FieldIDToDelete) in 
C:\Code\Local\WebApp.E2e\PageObjects\ApplicationSummary.cs:line 280
 at Test.E2e.Tests.ApplicationSummaryTest.Delete_Wider_General_Field_From_Application_Summary() in C:\Code\Local\WebApp.E2e\Tests\ApplicationSummaryTest.cs:line 45
```

Below is the HTML of the element on the web application:

```
<input ng-keypress="dialog.keypress($event)" md-autofocus="" ng-model="dialog.result" placeholder="Removal reason" class="ng-valid md-input ng-not-empty md-autofocus ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" aria-label="Removal reason" id="input_22" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Whether the RemovalReason element is button or text box. As per error, RemovalReason element is button and hence error is throwing during the clear action. Can you share the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared the `<input>` element with `placeholder` *attribute* as **Removal reason** is an *Angular* element and as you have to send text, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows :

```
IWebElement myElem = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='ng-valid md-input ng-not-empty md-autofocus ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse' and starts-with(@id,'input_') and @placeholder='Removal reason']")));
myElem.Click();
myElem.Clear();
myElem.SendKeys("Automated Test - Delete Field");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to clear text field before sending keys selenium c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283940/how-to-clear-text-field-before-sending-keys-selenium-c-sharp/51283995#51283995)
- [clear() does not clear the textbox with selenium and python and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151508/clear-does-not-clear-the-textbox-with-selenium-and-python-and-firefox/49151715#49151715)
- [python selenium can't clear input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635447/python-selenium-cant-clear-input-field/59635479#59635479)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, only I was trying to enter a dash in a date field that didn't allow dashes. I figured this out by manually entering a date with a dash and it did not populate. (The field also doesn't accept letters - just numbers). Now, my test enters a date without a dash and it passes successfully!