# clear() method leaves one unknown character in the input field using SeleniumWebdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

When clearing a input field using `clear()` method for chromedriver version 100.0.4896.127, leaves this special char in the field

```

```

This occured only on this chromedriver version.

Anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around solution:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a", Keys.DELETE)
```

Or

```
while (!inputField.getAttribute("value").equals("")) {
        inputField.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally while invoking [*`clear()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283995/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("elementCssSelector"))).clear();
```