# python selenium can't clear input field

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, webdriver

I try to select my input with selenium but when I use this it doesn't work:

```
driver = self.driver
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
password.clear()
password.send_keys(password)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# the sentence below doesn't work
password.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'a')
password.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
```

I am using Mac so Keys.CONTROL doesn't work, can anyone help me how to select the input or how to clear it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the page loading after `password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`?

Comment: How are you getting `password_alem`? Can you add more of your code?

Comment: yes, but not if the password is wrong

Comment: @Jortega sorry it was a copy mistake

Comment: See the answer below and remember to mark it if it solves your issue.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac cannot use `COMMAND` you need `Keys.BACKSPACE`
Try:

```
driver = self.driver
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
password.clear()
password.send_keys(password)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
#or
#time.sleep(1)
for i in range(len(password)):
    password.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Comment: thank, I tied this before, but the delay is too long, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 5):

You have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))
  password.click()        
  password.clear()
  password.send_keys("Tijmen")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
  password.click()
  password.clear()
  password.send_keys("Tijmen")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to clear text field before sending keys selenium c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283940/how-to-clear-text-field-before-sending-keys-selenium-c-sharp)
- [clear() does not clear the textbox with selenium and python and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151508/clear-does-not-clear-the-textbox-with-selenium-and-python-and-firefox/49151715#49151715)
- [InvalidElementStateException when attempting to clear text through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528377/invalidelementstateexception-when-attempting-to-clear-text-through-selenium/50529031#50529031)

Comment: thanks for your code, but it only clicks on the input field, it doesn't select it..?

Comment: `click()` and `clear()` back to back should do the job. If you are observing a different behavior can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: Okay, so I am trying to login into instagram, because I have a list with all my passwords and I always forget my passwords so I created a script were I try to test every password, if it doesn't work I want my script to clear the old input and try a new password. but it still doesn't work...